# search for value n multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a CSV file with 3 columns: date, bookname, and author. I'm importing them into an array and splitting them to separate columns. Now, I want to search and get the index position date I search for in the array based on date input. I'm unable to make it work and I'm getting an error: Undefined variable: array_search

```
<?php
$fulldata=array();
$lines = file('e:/bookdetails.csv');
foreach($lines as $data)
{
$fulldata[]=explode(',',$data);
}


<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="mydate" />Enter  date<br>
<button type="submit" name="submit" ><strong>Search</strong></button>
</form>

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$mydate=$_POST['mydate'];
$pos=$array_search("7/1/2019",array_column($fulldata, 0));
    echo " index " .$pos;
}
?>
```

Comment: Typo: You have a `$` before the function name `array_search`.

Comment: error stopped coming but its not returning the position $pos

Comment: Make sure you don't have extra whitespace around the date in the CSV file.

Comment: I have tried your code and it's working. I just replace `7/1/2019` date to `$mydate` variable in your code and the return proper index. Also remove `$` from `$array_search` function.